# Pushing nested properties into array of a JSON in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I have a JSON response like this:

```
    {
      "AD": {
        "name": "Andorra",
        "native": "Andorra",
        "phone": "376",
        "continent": "EU",
        "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "languages": [
          "ca"
        ]
      },
      "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "native": "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    "phone": "971",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Abu Dhabi",
    "currency": "AED",
    "languages": [
      "ar"
    ]
  },
```

And I want to iterate over the countries capitals, only. But as for now I can only get the key of the contry and i'm not being able to reach the nested properties. I'm using this code in my subscription:

```
subscribe(data=>{
        let cityProps=Object.keys(data);
        let cityList=[]
        for(let prop in cityProps){
          cityList.push(cityProps[prop]);

        }
        this.cities=cityList;
        console.log(cityList)
```

I understand that this logic will only give me an array of "AD","AE" and so on. But how can I get the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like this -

```
for(let prop in cityProps){
     cityList.push(cityProps[prop].name);
}
```

```js
const a = {
      "AD": {
        "name": "Andorra",
        "native": "Andorra",
        "phone": "376",
        "continent": "EU",
        "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "languages": [
          "ca"
        ]
      },
      "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "native": "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    "phone": "971",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Abu Dhabi",
    "currency": "AED",
    "languages": [
      "ar"
    ]
  }}
  
 const b = [];
 for(let prop in a){
     b.push(a[prop].name);
}
 
 console.log(b);
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but this only because I can modify my data structure; but what if I get this JSON from a remote server? That was my real issue

Comment: then also it should work, no need to modify data structure, it works as per you posted code in the question.

Comment: the problem is that I was still using object.keys with your updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
      "AD": {
        "name": "Andorra",
        "native": "Andorra",
        "phone": "376",
        "continent": "EU",
        "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "languages": [
          "ca"
        ]
      },
      "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "native": "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    "phone": "971",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Abu Dhabi",
    "currency": "AED",
    "languages": [
      "ar"
    ]
  }};

//this will return array of capitals
Object.values(data).map(e => e.capital);
```

Comment: it's returning all the keys and values inside each country and it's not an array, but it's also a handy solution, thanks!

Comment: @Mellville Can you specify a sample response you are looking for?